# Customize and Save the Word Quick Access Toolbar

Tags: microsoft-word, toolbar

It is possible to save the customization of the Paint and Wordpad quick access toolbars via Regedit in...

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Paint\Ribbon
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Wordpad\Ribbon
```

But where is the registry key that controls the Word quick access toolbar? other than in hexadecimal code as in the key...

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Data
```

**obs: corrected title and message.**

Answer (score 1):

Both Paint and WordPad are very simple tools, and the toolbar is not customizable.

There are some registry changes for some [WordPad defaults](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/143952-wordpad-custom-template-workaround.html) but not the toolbar

You can [customize the Quick Access toolbar](https://www.shorttutorials.com/windows8-paint/customize-quick-access-toolbar.html) (which is about managing Files) in MS Paint.

Overall your options are very limited.

Comment: Really, I made a lousy mess. This is about the Quick Access Toolbar, many thanks for the fix, John. It is in fact very limited in terms of customization, but preferable for me as I need access in a few clicks and more space for viewing files, really difficult things with the ribbon layout.